# Como puedo alinear las tarjetas de bootstraps hechas en JS, me quedan en una columna y en forma vertical

Tags: javascript, bootstrap, card

```js
let camisetas = [
  {
    id: 1,
    nombre: "Camiseta Peñarol",
    precio: 2500,
    imagen: "../assets/images/manya.png",
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    nombre: "Camiseta Boca",
    precio: 2500,
    imagen: "../assets/images/Boca.jfif",
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    nombre: "Camiseta Liverpool",
    precio: 2500,
    imagen: "../assets/images/Liverpool.png",
  },
  {
    id: 4,
    nombre: "Camiseta Barcelona",
    precio: 2500,
    imagen: "../assets/images/barcelona2.png",
  },
];

const contenedor = document.getElementById("container");

$(document).ready();

for (const camiseta of camisetas) {
  $("#camisetasFut").prepend(`
  <Div class="container">
    <div class="row row-md-4 ">
      <div class="col-md-3  ">
        <div class="card-group">
         <img src=${camiseta.imagen} class="card-img-top tarjeta" alt="Camiseta">
          <div class="card-body">
            <h5 class="card-title"><hr>${camiseta.nombre}</h5>
            <p class="card-text">Camiseta Original ${camiseta.precio}.</p>
              <div class="d-grid gap-2">
                <button class="btn btn-dark comprar" role="button">Comprar</button>
              </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div> 
  </div>`);
```

```css
html {
  background-color: #fdf9ff;
}

@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat:wght@300&display=swap");
body {
  line-height: 1.5;
  font-family: "Montserrat", sans-serif;
}


/* Carousel */
.carousel-inner > .item > img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 570px;
}

/* Camisetas - Ropa - cards */
.camiseta {
  width: auto;
  height: 200px;
}

/* Footer */

* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.conte {
  max-width: 1170px;
  margin: auto;
}
ul {
  list-style: none;
}
.footer {
  background-color: #24262b;
  padding: 70px 0;
}
.pie h4 {
  color: #ffff;
  font-size: 18px;
  text-transform: capitalize;
  margin-bottom: 35px;
  font-weight: 500;
  position: relative;
}
.pie ul li {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.pie ul li a {
  font-size: 16px;
  text-transform: capitalize;
  color: #ffff;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: 300;
  color: #bbb;
  display: block;
}
.pie ul li a:hover {
  color: #ffff;
  padding-left: 8px;
}
.social-links a {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 40px;
  width: 40px;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 40px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  color: #ffff;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
}
.social-links a:hover {
  color: #24262b;
  background-color: #ffff;
}
@media (max-width: 767px) {
  .pie {
    width: 50%;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
  }
}
@media (max-width: 574px) {
  .pie {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title id="pentania">Todas Las Canchas</title>

  <!-- CSS Font Awesome -->
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.3/css/all.min.css"
      integrity="sha512-iBBXm8fW90+nuLcSKlbmrPcLa0OT92xO1BIsZ+ywDWZCvqsWgccV3gFoRBv0z+8dLJgyAHIhR35VZc2oM/gI1w=="
      crossorigin="anonymous"
      referrerpolicy="no-referrer"/>

  <!-- CSS Google Fonts -->
    <link
      href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:300,400,700"
      rel="stylesheet"
      type="text/css"
    />
    <link
      href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
      rel="stylesheet"
      integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../assets/css/styles.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
<!-- inicio Primera Barra Header-->
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-dark">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <a class="navbar-brand mx-auto fs-2 text-white text-center" href="#">Todas las Canchas</a>
    <form class="d-flex">
      <input
        class="form-control me-2"
        type="search"
        placeholder="Buscar"
        aria-label="Search"/>
      <button class="btn btn-outline-light" type="submit">Buscar</button>
    </form>
</nav>
<!-- Fin primera Barra Header-->
<!-- inicio Segunda Barra Header-->
<div class="container mt-3">
<div class="row">
  <div class="col text-center">
    <ul class="nav nav-pills">
      <li class="nav-item dropdown ">
        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle text-dark text-center " 
            data-bs-toggle="dropdown" 
            href="#" 
            role="button" 
            aria-expanded="false"><strong>Futbol</strong>
          </a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-dark ">
          <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Camisetas</a></li>
          <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Calzados deportivos</a></li>
          <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Más..</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="col text-center">
    <ul class="nav nav-pills">
      <li class="nav-item dropdown ">
        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle text-dark text-center" 
            data-bs-toggle="dropdown" 
            href="#" 
            role="button" 
            aria-expanded="false"><strong>Basketball</strong> 
          </a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-dark ">
          <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Camisetas</a></li>
          <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Calzados deportivos</a></li>
          <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Más..</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="col text-center">
    <ul class="nav nav-pills">
      <li class="nav-item dropdown ">
        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle text-dark" 
            data-bs-toggle="dropdown" 
            href="#" 
            role="button" 
            aria-expanded="false"><strong>Rugby</strong>  
          </a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-dark ">
          <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Camisetas</a></li>
          <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Calzados deportivos</a></li>
          <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Más..</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="col text-center">
    <ul class="nav nav-pills">
      <li class="nav-item dropdown ">
        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle text-dark" 
            data-bs-toggle="dropdown" 
            href="#" 
            role="button" 
            aria-expanded="false"><strong>Jockey</strong> 
          </a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-dark ">
          <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Camisetas</a></li>
          <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Calzados deportivos</a></li>
          <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Más..</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>        
  </div>        
</div>
</div>
<hr>
<!-- fin segunda Barra Header-->
<!-- Titulo -->
   <div class="container">
     <div class="row">
       <div class="col text-center p-4 ">
         <h2> <strong>Camisetas de Futbol</strong> </h2>
       </div>
     </div>
   </div>
<!-- Titulo -->

<!-- Camisetas-->
<div id="camisetasFut"></div>
 
   <h1 class= 'text-center hide'>Compras</h1>
    <div id='container'class="row">
    </div>

    <div class="row hide" id="myForm">
      <div class="col-3 col-md-2 ">
      </div>
      <div class="col-6 col-md-8 p-5 text-center">
        <section class="customer" id="comprador">
          <h2><strong>Ingrese sus Datos</strong> </h2>

         <div class="mb-2">
           <label for="exampleFormControlTextarea1" class="form-label">Nombre</label>
           <input class="form-control form-control-sm" id="name" type="text" placeholder="Ingrese su nombre completo" aria-label=".form-control-sm example">
          </div>
          <div class="mb-2">
            <label for="exampleFormControlTextarea1" class="form-label">Movil</label>
            <input class="form-control form-control-sm" id='movil' type="number" placeholder="Ingrese su Nº de móvil" aria-label=".form-control-sm example">
           </div>
           <div class="mb-2">
            <label for="exampleFormControlTextarea1" class="form-label">Teléfono</label>
            <input class="form-control form-control-sm" id='phone' type="number" placeholder="Ingrese su Nº de teléfono fijo" aria-label=".form-control-sm example">
           </div>    
           <div class="mb-2">
            <label for="exampleFormControlTextarea1" class="form-label">Dirección</label>
            <input class="form-control form-control-sm" id='adress' type="text" placeholder="Ingrese su dirección" aria-label=".form-control-sm example">
           </div>
          <button class="btn btn-dark" id="enviar">Enviar</button>          
        </section>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-3 col-md-2">
    </div>      
    
    <div id="agradecimiento" class="text-center">
      <h3 id="mensaje">Gracias por tu compra, los datos fueron enviados</h3>
    </div>
<!-- Camisetas-->
<!-- Footer -->
  <footer class= "footer mt-4">
    <div class="container conte">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-4 pie">
          <h4>Empresa</h4>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Sobre Nosotros</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Nuestros Servicios</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Politica de Privacidad</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Contáctanos</a></li>
          </ul>         
        </div>
        <div class="col-4 pie">
          <h4>Ayuda</h4>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Preguntas</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Envíos</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Devoluciones</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Órdenes</a></li>
          </ul>         
        </div>
        <div class="col-4 pie">
          <h4>Síguenos</h4>
            <div class="social-links">
              <a href="#"><i class="fab fa-facebook-f"></i></a>
              <a href="#"><i class="fab fa-twitter"></i></a>
              <a href="#"><i class="fab fa-instagram"></i></a>
              <a href="#"><i class="fab fa-linkedin-in"></i></a>
            </div>                 
        </div>
      </div>      
    </div>
  </footer>
<!--Fin de Footer -->
<!-- jQuery -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- JS de Bootstrap -->
 <script
   src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.0/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"
   integrity="sha384-U1DAWAznBHeqEIlVSCgzq+c9gqGAJn5c/t99JyeKa9xxaYpSvHU5awsuZVVFIhvj"
   crossorigin="anonymous">
 </script>
<!-- JS Propio -->
<script src="../scripts/js/camisetas.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El tema es que quiero que las tarjetas me queden en forma horizontal y no en forma vertical, como muestro en la imagen, alguien me puede dar una mano para dejarlas horizontales? He probado leyendo en Bootstrap 5, en la parte de tarjetas y grilla y no he podido encontrar la solución.

Envío, el HTML completo y CSS completo también. El JS no se vincular con el HTML en la consulta que estoy haciendo, capaz que por eso tampoco se ven las tarjetas...

Desde ya muchas gracias!

Comment: Deberias agregar tu HTML

Comment: ¿Seria mucha molestia que pusieras mas contexto?  Es decir, el HTML por ejemplo, la version de bootstrap, el cierre del `for` por si acaso hay algo mas despues, etc... Léete como crear un [ejemplo minimo, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Estas creando un container, row y col por cada camiseta. Saca el container el row y el col fuera del for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema es que por cada iteración del for estás haciendo una row nueva, por lo que te quedarán una encima de la otra, además de un container que en principio no es necesario.

Con agregar la clase "d-flex" al contenedor padre (camisetasFut) sería suficiente para que queden horizaontales, pero si achicas la pantalla se deformaría todo.

Lo ideal es que solo el `div` con id camisetasFut tenga la clase "row", y luego en cada iteración del `for` sacar el "container" y sacar la "row" con sus respectivas `</div>`. Puede ser algo así por ejemplo:

**HTML**

```
  <body>
    <div id="camisetasFut" class="row"></div>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
  </body>
```

**JavaScript** (Es lo puse en un archivo a parte, app.js en la misma carpeta que el índex.html)

```
for (const camiseta of camisetas) {
  $("#camisetasFut").prepend(`
        <div class="col-md-6 col-xl-4">
          <div class="card-group">
           <img src=${camiseta.imagen} class="card-img-top tarjeta" alt="Camiseta">
            <div class="card-body">
              <h5 class="card-title"><hr>${camiseta.nombre}</h5>
              <p class="card-text">Camiseta Original ${camiseta.precio}.</p>
                <div class="d-grid gap-2">
                  <button class="btn btn-dark comprar" role="button">Comprar</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>`);
}
```

Modifiqué esta línea en el script también:

```
<div class="col-md-6 col-xl-4">
```

Lo que hace junto con el `for` es crear una col por cada iteración que tendrá el siguiente comportamiento.
A partir de **md** cada col será de 6, y a partir de **xl** será de 4. De esa forma si está por debajo de md se mantiene en 12, es decir 1 col por row, si está entre md y xl pasará a ser 6, es decir 2 col por row, y si supera xl será de 4, es decir 3 col por row.
Como cada Row puede tener un **máximo de 12** en la suma de todos los elementos, todos los que superen 12 pasarán a posicionarse debajo, y así consecutivamente, sin importar cuantas agregues.
Es una manera sencilla de lograr un comportamiento responsivo.

Espero ayude a evacuar tu duda, quedo a las órdenes.

Comment: Muchas gracias Luis , estamos cerca!! Por lo menos 3 se alinearon y una quedo abajo pero pienso que es por un tema de tamaño. Pero fue muy útil!!

Comment: Si le pusiste col-3 y tenes 4 una se va a ir abajo. Podes cambiar eso con media querys o tambie con md sg lg de bootstrap

Comment: Al final entró con el siguiente código:

for (const camiseta of camisetas) {
  $("#camisetasFut").prepend(`
        <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-3">

Comment: Me alegro mucho, a las órdenes!